# knockout.js data-binding each object in JSON array to a <td>

Tags: json, data-binding, knockout.js

So, suppose I have this web service that returns a C# List serialized to JSON, so what I get back in the client, in the **viewmodel**, is a JSON array:

```
[
    {"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 30},
    {"Id": 2, "Name": "Mike", "Age": 25},
    {"Id": 3, "Name": "Lana", "Age": 28},
]
```

Although this is not the actual data I'm working with, It'll be sufficient for the example.

What I'm trying to accomplish, by using knockout.js, is to **data-bind each** element in the above array (viewmodel) to a **td** tag inside a table in my view. So, in this example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td> // this would represent John
        <td></td> // this would represent Mike
        <td></td> // this would represent Lana
    </tr>
</table>
```

Important to notice that don't want just to data-bind an element's property to a td's attribute, like

```
<td data-bind="text: vm.Name">
```

I wanted the td tag to, somehow, represent the whole person element (object).

Comment: [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to this question is in a different question, similar to this one, also made by me. Here's the link:

[knockout $data binding to an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124322/knockout-data-binding-to-an-html-element)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a pre tag like this inside the each loop in the table

```
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
```

Full example would be something like this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: objects">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will give you a pre tag with the objects JSON inside the table. I assumed that name of the value was "objects" but you can change it to whatever it needs to be.