# knockout $data binding to an HTML element

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

So, suppose I have this viewmodel named **people** which consists of an **array of person object literals**, like

```
[{ name = John, age = 30, sex = male },
 { name = Mike, age = 29, sex = male },
 { name = Anna, age = 28, sex = female }]
```

And suppose I wanted to data-bind each person to an `<li>`, like

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

**But**, is it possible, maybe through **`data-bind="with: $data"`**, to bind the whole person object to the `<li>` so, for example, when I click the `<li>` some other `<div>` displays the rest of the information, which in this example would be age and sex?

It's like I wanted the `<li>` to hold the person object data, so I could use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you would want to create like a `selectedPerson` observable at the view model level and then you could do something like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.selectedPerson">
         <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
         <div data-bind="visible: $parent.selectedPerson() === $data">
              <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You could certainly use a link/button around the name, if you like. When you click on it, `selectedPerson` will be used as the handler and passed the current data as its first argument.  Since, `selectedPerson` is actually an observable, it will populate it with the data as its value.

Otherwise, you could certainly have another area to display the details where you do:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedPerson">
   ....
</div>
```

Quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8dRZ4/